# Xcode indexing frequently and searching in framework files/takes time when loading project

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, indexing, xcode4.5

I am having a weird problem with Xcode where it keep indexing and takes long time to do that. Search functionality also does not work properly. It searches in all framework/library files instead of project files. I tried with my other project but that project has no problem. So I guess it is something wrong with my project...But I am not able to find out. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out answer to my own question... I deleted workspace file in .xcodeproject package. Then When I opened the project in xcode, it still took time because it has whole "Application" folder under the project. I removed the reference to it and reopened it and now it works fine. It didn't affect the git repository for me.